# parsing dates in csv does not work with some files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dt_parser = lambda x: dt.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv('HDFCBANK-TickData - Master09apr.csv',
             parse_dates=['Time'],
             date_parser=dt_parser
             )
```

This works for one file but does not for other
1. Both have same date format and same source.
2. copy/paste and using date values from notepad works:

```
dt.strptime('09-04-2020 15:58:02','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
dt.strptime('13-04-2020 15:59:40','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

[Notepad comparison for date values][1]

dt.strptime('09-04-2020 15:58:02','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 9, 15, 58, 2)
dt.strptime('13-04-2020 15:59:40','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 13, 15, 59, 40)

You can check both CSVs from:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiCdYwgWz0aTk5UNNPohj6r0-qGFWw?e=MbKXt7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a row in second file Master09Apr, which might be breaking the code.

> 09-04-2020 09:01:01,888.70,888.70,888.70,888.70,6866
>   Time,Open,Close,High,Low,Volume 09-04-2020
>   15:58:02,925.05,925.05,925.05,925.05,200

Please remove this line and try again.

Comment: I tried and check, but dont see the problem, were you able to check at your end?

Comment: Check Line 397, it should not be there.